# How do send a link to a document using word vba CDO email process?

Tags: vba, email, hyperlink, ms-word

Does anybody know how to send a link to a word document via email in word vba? I want to use gmail not outlook. I found a solution for outlook:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail10.htm

Is there anyway that can be modified to work using gmail?

I modified: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm  to work with gmail, and it is working fine. I just need to add a link to the body of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `htmlBody` property instead of `TextBody` and use an `<a>` tag in the HTML.

Comment: Hello!thank you for responding to me. It works, but it doesn't convert to a link. Any ideas?

Comment: I posted the code as an answer, because I wasn't allowed to edit my post. Take a look. Thank you!

Comment: You can't use both body types.  If you use `textBody` your email will be sent as text.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know how to send my code...So I posted it as an answer. Hope that's ok. Also I get a strange run time error that I wasn't getting before. Other than that it works.

Thanks!
Danielle

Option Explicit                                  '  Modified for dSavage

'If you have a GMail account then you can try this example to use the GMail smtp server
'The example will send a small text message
'You must change four code lines before you can test the code

'.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "Full GMail mail address"
'.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "GMail password"

'Use your own mail address to test the code in this line
'.To = "Mail address receiver"

'Change YourName to the From name you want to use
'.From = """YourName"" "

'If you get this error : The transport failed to connect to the server
'then try changing the SMTP port from 25 to 465

Sub CDO_Mail_Example()
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim sAddForm As String
    Dim sForm As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

```
Dim iSMTP_Port As Integer
Dim sFirstReviewer  As String
Dim sUserName  As String
Dim sGmailPassword As String

sFirstReviewer = Range("F4").Value
sUserName = Range("F6").Value & "@indicate1.com"
sGmailPassword = Range("F8").Value
iSMTP_Port = Range("F10").Value   '25 at Indicate;  465  away.
sAddForm = Range("I12").Value
'sForm = Range("F4").Value

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
```

If sAddForm = "Yes" Then
        sForm = "Z:\Quality# # Document_Development# Documents_for_Review\12002-01-01 Company Handbook.doc"
   Else
        sForm = ""
    End If

```
Debug.Print "sForm = " & sForm ' *******************************************
Debug.Print "sUserName = " & sUserName ' *******************************************

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = sUserName
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "Micro5cope"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = iSMTP_Port    '25 at Indicate;  465  away.
    .Update
End With

strbody = "To " & sFirstReviewer & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 4" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Z:\Quality\# # Document_Development\# Documents_for_Review\12000-00-00 Tables 9-11 Template OLD - TEST.doc" & vbNewLine & _
            sForm & vbNewLine

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = sFirstReviewer & "@indicate1.com"
    .CC = ""     'sUserName & "; " & "johanson111@comcast.net"
    .BCC = ""
    .From = sUserName
    .Subject = "Test Message"
     .textbody = strbody
    .HtmlBody = "<A HREF=""http://www.google.com/"">Google Page</A>"
    .AddAttachment "Z:\Quality\# # Document_Development\12001-02-01 Document Review Form.pdf"
    .AddAttachment "Z:\Quality\# # Document_Development\12001-02 Document Review Draft 9.doc"
   .Send
End With

Debug.Print "CC = " & sUserName  ' *******************************************
```

End Sub